# Hola, ¿Alguien me puede decir porque mi resultado viene en una linea y en otra un NONE?

Tags: python

```
def invertir():

    return "".join(reversed(p))



def Verificador():

    if invertir ==p:

        return print("Es palíndromo")

    else:

       return  print("No es palíndromo")

p=input("Ingrese una palabra en minsculas: ")

print("\n",Verificador())

print("\n",invertir())
```

Answer (score 1):

`Print` devuelve un `None`, al hacer un return  `print("No es palíndromo")` realmente tu función retorna un `None`

Regresa únicamente el string para que funcione

```
def Verificador():

    if invertir ==p:

        return"Es palíndromo"

    else:

       return "No es palíndromo"
```

También es importante indicar que `p` siempre es mejor pasarla como parámetro, quedando tu código así

Y que en `invertir == p` estas diciendo que si una función (invertir) es igual a un string, obviamente, esto jamás se va a dar, para poder usarlo debes ejecutar la función, quedando tu código así.

```
def invertir(p):

    return "".join(reversed(p))



def Verificador(p):

    if invertir(p) == p:

        return "Es palíndromo"

    else:

       return "No es palíndromo"

p = input("Ingrese una palabra en minúsculas: ")

print("\n",Verificador(p))

print("\n",invertir(p))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!